# How do I calculate the pressure $p_0$ on top of the water reservoir?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, bernoulli-equation

Can anyone help me with this question, I can't get the right answer :-)

A water reservoir with depth D=200m, which is placed H=500m above on a mountain. A pipe is placed from the bottom of the reservoir to the bottom of the mountain. This pipe has two cross-section areas $A_1=10m^2$ and $A_2=5m^2$. The atmospheric pressure in the bottom is $p_2=100kPa$ and the air density down here is $\rho_2=1 kg/m^3$ and waters density is $\rho_w=1000 kg/m^3$.

[image]

**What is the atmospheric pressure $p_0$ at the surface of the reservoir?**

It has to be 93 kPa

---

---

My attempt on a solution:

I know I need to use Bernoulli's equations:

$$
p_{0}+\rho_w g(H+D)+\frac{1}{2} \rho_w v_{0}^{2}=k
$$
$$
p_{1}+\rho_w g H+\frac{1}{2} \rho_w v_{1}^{2}=k
$$
$$
p_{2}+\rho_w g(0)+\frac{1}{2} \rho_w v_{2}^{2}=k
$$

And the continuity equation.
$$
A_{1} v_{1}=A_{2} v_{2}
$$

Usually I would assume $v_{0} \simeq 0$, but they don't mention that the surface area is much larger than the two cross sections. So can I still assume this, or should I forget about the first equation?

But so far (assuming v0=0), I got 4 equations and 5 unknowns.

We are assuming the water got the same density. And if the water is a standing liquid (v0=0), we could calculate $$
p_{1}=p_{0}+\rho_{w} g D
$$

But solving this system of equations gives me: $$
p_{0}=p_{2}-\rho_{w} g(H+D),
$$ which is completely wrong, since I get a negative pressure and the cross sections areas becomes irrelevant. How do I solve this exercise? And why do I even need to know the density of the air at the bottom of the mountain?

Comment: Static water pressure only depends on depth below the surface, so you don't need most of the data in your problem.  Also, at the bottom of a 700 m column of water, it's not possible to have a pressure of 100 kPa. The pressure should be at least 70 times that value.  Also, note that the pressure $P_0$ should be equal to the local atmospheric pressure.

Comment: @DavidWhite But my final result also gives me, that the pressure p2 only depends on the atmospheric pressure p0 and the depth below the surface (and water density + g). But why is the correct result of the pressure $P_0=93kPa$?

But the water is not static, so that's probably where the issue are.

Comment: $P_0$ is a boundary condition, not something that you calculate.  You start at the value of $P_0$, and calculate pressures going down the mountain from there.

Comment: @DavidWhite: *"it's not possible to have a pressure of 100 kPa"*. I think it's meant to be the **atmospheric pressure** at $P2$.

Comment: @DavidWhite - Well, it's an exam question and I know the correct answer is $P_0=93kPa$ - So it has to be possible to calculate.

Comment: @Gert, I realized that as I was posting my answer.  However, I must say that the problem statement is very ambiguous at best.  If the question wants you to calculate $P_0$ from $P_2$, none of the information regarding water flows and cross-sectional areas is relevant.

Comment: @DavidWhite: yes it's a crap question with red herrings thrown in for extra  confusion. Pity the children!

Comment: @DavidWhite - But are you sure. Does the pressure only depends on the depth of the water. I thought it would only be in static situations?

<br> <br> But why do I get a pressure $p_0=-6765 kPa$ using this equation: $p_{0}=p_{2}-\rho_{w} g(H+D)$ ?
I'm supposed to get 93 kPa

Comment: @mhj, what is the relative roughness of the water pipe?  Does the water at A2 just fly into the atmosphere or is there some type of restriction at the bottom of the mountain?  What are the temperature and viscosity of the water?  These are unknown, and it's much easier to use an equation that deals only with air, with that equation accounting for air's compressibility.

Comment: @mhj, your equation for $P_0$ MUST use the value of pressure at the bottom of the mountain that is due to total pressure inside the pipe, not atmospheric pressure at that point.

Comment: @DavidWhite - I know it would be easier to calculate the pressure from air's density. But the density is not constant, and I don't think I got enough information to be able to describe air's density as a function of the height.

Comment: @mhj, the equation for atmospheric pressure vs. height should be in your physics book.  If not, I KNOW that you can find it on Google.

Comment: @DavidWhite - But in all other exercises I have done using Bernoulli's equations. You would usually assume that the pressure P2 just at the end of the pipe is equal to the atmospheric pressure. But I haven't experienced an exercise where the velocity of the water stream, wasn't given at one point.

Comment: @mhj, for the particular derivation that you did, you must use the pressure inside the pipe.  That is why you are getting a negative pressure for $P_0$.  If you don't want to use this value, you will need to do a different derivation.

Comment: @DavidWhite - I appreciate your help. But I can't find any equation describing the atmospheric pressure as function of altitude, temperature etc. And I don't got access to internet at the exam, so I should be able to solve this without google.

Comment: @mhj, see https://www.math24.net/barometric-formula/

Comment: @DavidWhite - Then there is something that I have completely misunderstood. I have calculated a ton of similar questions like this one: http://tinypic.com/r/zl7of7/9 - Where you have to assume that the pressure at point 1 and point 3 are equal in order to solve the exercise.

Comment: Assuming that the air density doesn't change much between the ground level and the top of the reservoir, $\Delta p=\rho g h=(1)(9.8)(700)=6860 Pa=6.86 kPa$.  So the pressure at the top of the reservoir is 100 - 6.86 = 93 kPa.

Answer (score 1):

Either you are leaving something out or it is a very bad exam question.  The problem does not indicate that the water is moving, so presumably it is a hydrostatic problem. In that case the water does not matter and you just need to know how the atmospheric presure varies with height. To know that you have to know the air temperature profile which is not given.

If the water *is* moving, and you are supposed to use Bernoulli,  then you need to know the flow rate at the exit point, which is not given.

Comment: You are correct: there is no solution here w/o extra information.